# display image from RSS FEED <image> element in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart, rss

I want to show image from RSS FEED where image is stored in image tag. But item.enclouse.url is not getting the image. How can i display the image?

```dart
<item>
<title>প্রথম আলো</title>
<atom:link href="https://www.prothomalo.com/feed/" type="application/rss+xml" rel="self"/>
<link>https://www.prothomalo.com/</link>
<description>
Online Latest Bangla News/Article - Sports, Crime, Entertainment, , Business, Politics, Education, Opinion, Lifestyle, Photo, Video, Travel, National, World
</description>
<image>
<url>
https://paloimages.prothom-alo.com/contents/cache/images/154x154/uploads/default/2016/03/15/dc5a51021b9c4eb8ef5e86dc794054e1-palo-logo.jpg
</url>
</image>
</item>
```